# Identity elements and functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assuming a function $f(x,y) := (x+5)\cdot y$ is it possible for $(\mathbb N,f)$ to have an identity element.
I originally thought no, as an operation is always applied to $x$ that will permanently change the output.

Edit: additionally what is meant by $(\mathbb N\backslash\{0\},f)$ ?

Comment: (N,f) is referring to the set of natural numbers with the binary operation f.  If it happens to have the additional necessary properties, it would be called a group.  (N\{0},f) is the same except instead of the naturals including zero the set is instead the positive natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,y)$ has an identity element $x$ is equivalent to $f(x,y)=f(y,x)=y$.

$(x+5)y=(y+5)x=y$, $(x+5)y=(y+5)x$ implies that $5y=5x$ and $x=y$. So if $x\neq y$, $f(x,y)\neq f(y,x)$ and you cannot have an identity element.

Comment: Does that mean $x$ is the identity element iff $x = y$?

Comment: This means there does not exist an identity since $\mathbb{N}$ has more than one element, and if $x$ is the identity, choose, $y\neq x$ you cannot have $f(x,y)=f(y,x)=y$ since $f(x,y)\neq f(y,x)$.

Comment: There is an important part missing in your first sentence: “for all $y$”.